# Draw error when moving from desktop to android... android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474)

Tags: android, libgdx, frame, draw

I am getting a lot of different errors when trying to make my app work on android, when it works perfectly on my desktop. I've managed most of the errors but this error I cant figure out. I tried removing every drawable texture or animation one by one but still got the same error even with an empty screen.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 96
               java.lang.NullPointerException
               at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:443)
               at com.jteck.game.states.PlayState.<init>(PlayState.java:118)
               at com.jteck.game.states.MenuState.handleInput(MenuState.java:56)
               at com.jteck.game.states.MenuState.update(MenuState.java:78)
               at com.jteck.game.states.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:31)
               at com.jteck.game.Hangman.render(Hangman.java:36)
               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474)
               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: so, what is on line 118 in the `PlayState` class?

Comment: wow such a noob.. not only did u help me fix the problem.. but also taught me a new lesson.. java x .. x = line number.. soo cool.. if u make a solution i will tag it as the right answer .. thanx again

Comment: Glad I could help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something causes the `NullPointerException` on the line 118 in the `PlayState` class.